# Sas how to work with columns whose name consists of two parts, first is the same, but second different

Tags: sas

I have a few columns in SAS for which name starts with `100_Section_xxx`. So first part of the name is the same, while second part (`xxx`) is different. 
I want to write condition for every column such as `If 100_Section_xxx >1 then do error_100_Section_xxx ="yes"` How do I write it, in order Sas takes the second part of the name of `100_Section_xxx` and add `xxx` to the second part of the name of the column `error_100_Section_xxx`.

Comment: Variable names generally don't start with a digit.  If they do you need to use a *name literal* syntax.  Are the names actually the variable labels ? Can you show the `Proc CONTENTS` output for the data set ?  Can you show some specific example code of what you want instead just describing the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple macro and data step with an array:

This macro loops through a list of names (the XXX values) and lists variables that end with it.

```
%macro var_names(names, prefix=);
%local i n var;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&names));
%do i=1 to &n;
   %let var=%scan(&names,&i);
   &prefix.&var
%end;
%mend;
```

Now use that, a data step, and 2 arrays.

```
data have;
_100_Section_a = 1;
_100_Section_b = 0;
_100_Section_c = 10;
run;

data want;
set have;
array vars[*] %var_names(a b c, prefix=_100_Section_);

format %var_names(a b c, prefix=error_100_Section_) $8.;
array errors[*] %var_names(a b c, prefix=error_100_Section_);

do i=1 to dim(vars);
   if vars[i] > 1 then
      errors[i] = "yes";
end;

drop i;
run;
```

Note, I added a `_` to the variable names.  SAS variables cannot normally start with a number.

Comment: I'd be careful adding underscores to the beginning of names.  Some SAS products (I'm looking at you SAS XML Mapper) use hidden variables that begin with underscores.  By hidden - I mean they exist for the duration of certain steps and are then dropped in the background.  If your names conflict, your vars get overwritten and dropped without any warning. And these are common names so the chance of collision is high.  Lots of fun debugging that...